# Intent from fragment in drawer to LoginActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist

Hi I am trying to intent from a fragment in a drawer when I click on the button to the LoginActivity,but it's not working

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logout, container, false);
    btn=view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),LoginActivity.class));

        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

what shall I do?

Comment: The fragment that  I am in restart without taking me to the LoginActivity.There is no crashing

Comment: still not working

Comment: Your cod should work; do you get any errors?

Comment: No error but I am not able to move to the LoginActivity. It leaves me in this fragment

Comment: Can you debug and put a break point inside `onClick` and make sure it's called

Comment: Do I need to add something to the loginActivity?

Comment: You said in a comment "The fragment that I am in restart" which cannot happen unless your main activity is restarting or crashing.

Comment: I did that before the LoginActivity is called but I am locked in the fragment

Comment: Is this correct when you want to intent from navigation drawer fragment to any activity.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. Do what @Zain suggested in a comment and see if the onClick is really getting called